# Attempting to Vertical Align Paragraph Element

Tags: html, css

I have some simple css that is meant to display a paragraph element in the middle(vertically) of its parents div.

**My Problem:** The paragraph element does't vertically align to the middle it always sits at the top. This solution only has to work on Safari(iPad's Safari version specifically).

Do you know how to get my paragraph element to vertically align to the middle?

```
<html>
<head>

    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
        .ButtonBox { 
            cursor: pointer; 
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: blue;
            height: 200px;
        }

        .buttonBoxContainer { 
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    -->
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="ButtonBox">
        <p class="buttonBoxContainer">Press Me</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your box will always have a static height, you can use line-height to center the paragraph element, as shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m2x86u4g/).

If it won't be static, the best solution (In my experience) is to use javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>

        .ButtonBox { 
            cursor: pointer; 
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: blue;
            height: 200px;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .buttonBoxContainer { 
            cursor: pointer;
            line-height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="ButtonBox">
        <p class="buttonBoxContainer">Press Me</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, seriously, I thought there might be a solution in CSS3?

Comment: There is a CSS 3 solution. You can use the Flexible Box Layout Module of CSS 3. It's not well supported in IE. For details see here: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexible The http://flexiejs.com/playground/ has a nifty tool to play with the positioning.

Comment: @martineno I suggest this as an answer assuming ie support isn't required; it's fully supported by iOS safari. I'm ashamed I didn't think of this... Too many years coding with css2.

Comment: Thanks ArchNoob, I've fixed the link and added the code to the comment.

Comment: @SteveAdams Awesome!